# Every unitarily invariant matrix norm is sub-multiplicative?

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

Every unitarily invariant matrix norm is sub-multiplicative?

In R. Bhatia, Matrix Analysis, after Proposition IV.2.4, it says that "Every unitarily invariant matrix norm is sub-multiplicative". But I could not verify...

Here, a norm $||\cdot||$ is called unitarily invariant if $$||UAV||=||A||$$ for all matrix $A$, and unitary matrix $U,V$. And a norm is called sub-multiplicative if 
$$||AB||\leq ||A|| \cdot ||B||.$$

Comment: you also need to assume that $\|diag(1,0,\ldots,0)\|=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to combine IV.38 and IV.40. The first inequality says that $\|\cdot\|_\infty\leq\|\cdot\|$, where $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ is the operator norm and $\|\cdot\|$ is any unitarily invariant norm. Then, by IV.40,
$$
\|AB\|\leq\|A\|_\infty\,\|B\|\leq\|A\|\,\|B\|.
$$

Comment: It's perhaps worth mentioning that there is an additional assumption here, with regards to IV. 38, that the unitarily invariant norms $\|\cdot\|$ are normalized on the matrix $diag(1,0,\ldots,0)$ and not the identity matrix! For example, the unitarily invariant norm on $n\times n$ matrices $\|A\|_f:=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}tr(A^*A)}$ is not submultiplicative, since $\|I\|_f=1$.